# Unable to send data from Stripe webhook to Firebase database

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, webhooks

this is the webhook part

the payment is succeeding but it is not showing in firebase database

I have also tried different rules and payload code but it didn't work

this was the terminal command "stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/webhook"

these are the terminal responses

please check them also

[image: terminal]
[image: terminal]

webhook

```
import { buffer } from "micro";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'


//secure a connection to Firebase from backend
const serviceAccount = require('../../../permissions.jason');
const app = !admin.apps.length ? admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
}) 
  : admin.app();

// establish connection to stripe
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNNING_SECRET;
if (typeof endpointSecret !== "string") {
    console.error("Unexpected value for STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET");
    // potentially throw an error here
  }

const fulfillOrder = async (session) => {
    // console.log('Fulfilling order', session)

    return app
    .firestore()
    .collection("user")
    .doc(session.metadata.email)
    .collection("orders")
    .doc(session.id)
    .set({
        amount: session.amount_total / 100,
        amount_shipping: session.amount_total_details.amount_shipping / 100,
        images: JSON.parse(session.metadata.images),
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`success: order ${session.id} had been added to db`);
    });
};

export default async (req, res) =>{
    if(req.method === 'post'){
        const requestBuffer = await buffer(req);
        const payload = requestBuffer.toString();
        const sig = req.headers["stripe-signatur"];

        let event;

        // verify that the event posted came from stripe 
        try{
            const event= stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
                 req.rawBody.toString(),
                 sig,
                 endpointSecret);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('ERROR', err.message)
            return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${err.message}`)
        }

        //handle the checkout event
        if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
            const session = event.data.object;

            //fulfill the order...
            return fulfillOrder(session)
            .then(() => res.status(200))
            .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${err.message}`));
        }
    }
};

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
        externalResolver: true,
    },
};
```

firebase rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
      request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 5, 20);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You would want to test your local server by making a curl request to localhost:3000/api/webhook, to make sure it's working before doing a forward

Comment: how can you please tell

Comment: i am seeing the payment in stripe

Comment: yes, but after the payment is made, Stripe sent a request to your webhook endpoint, but your endpoint seems isn't able to receive the payload. I would suggest debug your local server first by smth like 
curl -X POST  http://localhost:3000/api/webhook

Comment: I will try it. Can I also contact you on discord if it dose not work

Comment: It is saying curl not recognizing

Comment: Even after installing curl it said the local host was not recognized